# Rewrite URL (folder name to custom URL with folder name as variable value) in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using these two lines to rewrite any URL like www.example.com/spyke (where spyke is a username, can be any username)..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)? [NC]

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)? http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L,R=301]
```

This ALMOST works, but the URL the system currently is redirected to is:

`www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=index.php`

.. instead of

`www.mydomain.com/index.php?id=82&user=spyke`

1) So I want to rewrite www.mydomain.com/spyke to `www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=spyke` .. Does anybody know how to achive this?

2) Also, I would like the user to see `www.example.com/spyke` in the address bar instead of `www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=spyke` - is this possible as well?

Thanks!!!!!

Roel

Here's my (updated) htaccess file btw:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/typo3/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* /index.php


RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
```

..

But this just results in this link:
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=index

Comment: How will a `user` be translated to `id`?

Comment: id is always 82; it's "user" that needs to be variable

Answer (score 1):

use this htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L]
```

**when this url : "www.example.com/spyke" requested**

**this htaccess load "index.php?id=82&user=spyke" instead of that !**

this lines load a file if exist!

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

and if requested URL not a file then load "index.php?id=82&user=[string]"

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)
However, this doesn't seem to work, nothing changes when I enter example.com/theuser .. I just receive a file/page not found error.

BTW, this works:

RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=$1 [L,R=301]

But results in www.example.com(..)&user=index instead of (..)&user=theusername

When I replace this ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? by this ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  -- replace ? for $ -- It doesn't work (no htaccess activity at all so to speak) .. So for some reason the $ at that place doesn't work for me...

Comment: @R_K: Clear you browser cache and retest.

Comment: Please see my (updated) htaccess file in my main post/question. This just results in http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=index instead of http://www.example.com/index.php?id=82&user=username

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^author/(.+)$ index.php?pagename=books&author=$1
```

I found it here: [Redirect number 5](https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/htaccess-redirect-rewrite-rules.html)

In your case, you should be using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=82&user=$1
```